# How can I unit test a PHP class method that executes a command-line program?

Tags: php, git, unit-testing, phpunit

For a PHP application I'm developing, I need to read the current git revision SHA which of course I can get easily by using shell_exec or backticks to execute the git command line client.

I have obviously put this call into a method of its very own, so that I can easily isolate and mock this for the rest of my unit tests. So my class looks a bit like this:

```
class Task_Bundle
{

    public function execute()
    {
        // Do things
        $revision = $this->git_sha();
        // Do more things
    }

    protected function git_sha()
    {
        return `git rev-parse --short HEAD`;
    }
}
```

Of course, although I can test most of the class by mocking git_sha, I'm struggling to see how to test the actual git_sha() method because I don't see a way to create a known state for it. I don't think there's any real value in a unit test that also calls `git rev-parse` to compare the results? I was wondering about at least asserting that the command had been run, but I can't see any way to get a history of shell commands executed by PHP - even if I specify that PHP should use BASH rather than SH the history list comes up empty, I presume because the separate backticks executions are separate terminal sessions.

I'd love to hear any suggestions for how I might test this, or is it OK to just leave that method untested and be careful with it when the app is being maintained in future?

Comment: I'd think that by definition, this is no longer a *unit* test...  You could test it, but not really separately from whatever stuff it uses.

Comment: I think what I want is still a unit test, but with the mocking taken one level further, by verifying that my code calls the public API of git in an expected manner. Eg, if git were a class in an external PHP library, I'd get a mock of it and assert that the rev-parse method was called with expected arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although you have accepted an answer, let me post something about what the way unittests should work because even if the solution posted does work and is indeed nice, it has some backdraws.

First of all you don't want to actually execute your command, as this would test an external software. From this moment you are depending on external stuff you cannot control (what happens if I want to test your software on my pc? Do I have to instal git or any git-mock?). What you really want to do is see if the command line command is correct and is executed well.

**As I struggled with this before, here is what I did**: I created a class which executes shell_exec. Everywhere I want to interact with the shell, I inject the class and use it. So for testing I can mock the class and see if the correct method is executed and if the correct parameters are set.

This has many benefits:

- I have one point of interacting with the shell. If anything changes in the future or if I have the need to do anything before executing the command, I can add the behaviour to the class. The PHP function is encapsulated nicely.
- It works on every PC, even if the shell_exec command does not work for any reason. The tests get executed on every pc (development machines, testserver, integration server) without the need to worry about external dependencies.

Of course to validate that your software works as a whole, you have to do integration tests which do not mock anything. But this is a totally different situation. Unittests should make sure your class (or method) does what it needs to do. Sometimes this is not clear cut, as you may decide to use a real class somewhere because mocking it would lead to much overhead. But, as far as I'm concerned, it's no longer a unit test by any means if it relys on external libraries/software which may not be installed or may not work for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

at least you could do something like checking for the retured string to match /^[abcdef0-9]{7}$/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - a nice idea, but I like @cHao's more which will also allow me to test that my code handles error conditions etc properly.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if you really wanted to, you could write a dummy `git` and prepend its location to your environment's `PATH`.  Have it do whatever validation you need to do, and then generate output consistent with what the real thing would do.  You could conceivably even have it forward stuff to the real `git`, if you wanted, but then you couldn't guarantee the results.

You'd have to be careful, though....You'd want do just enough so that the class can be fooled into thinking it's really `git`, but if you make it behave too much like the real thing does, that amounts to writing your own half-assed version of Git.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is a really neat solution, and the command line equivalent of $this->getMock(). I'm not actually looking to verify that git behaves as expected, so I think a simple script that writes the arguments received to disk for verification and outputs a fake sha as a return value is enough. If git change their command line arguments (essentially the API) I would need to handle thatbas is always the case with external libraries.  I'll try this when I'm back at a machine in a couple of hours just to be sure, but I think this is likely to be accepted. Thanks!

Comment: OK, that almost worked - I had to use `putenv` rather than setting $_ENV['PATH'] directly. I'm thinking about wrapping this functionality up into a CLI mock generator, to allow something like `$this->getMockCLI('git')->expectsArgs('rev-parse --short HEAD')->will($this->returnValue('abcdefg'));` which I think could be more generally useful, and allow testing with non-zero returns etc.